# Which android devices support the ADK / open accessory

Tags: android, adk

Is there a list anywhere of which Android devices (phones, tablets) support the ADK / accessory mode? From what I have read, I known that the Nexus One, Nexus S and Xoom do support it. Are there any other devices (custom ROMs included) that also support it? I have an ADK and can't get it working with my phone, I am basically looking for the cheapest phone that I can use with ADK.

** UPDATE ** I found this [list of tablets that work with the ADK](http://www.whizzosoftware.com/forums/blog/1/entry-47-tablets-and-the-android-open-accessory-development-kit-adk/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The offical Android 2.3.4 is based on the kernel 2.6.35, ADK need kernel 2.6.35. Some Android 2.3.4+ do not support adk because the kernel is not 2.6.35+. I used to copy the adk need jar into my milestone (Android 2.3.5, kernel 2.6.32, cm7), and install the DemoKit.apk but it doesn't work.
The phone I know ADK works: Nexus One, Nexus S, HTC Desire(need to do something to make it work)
I think if the phone have kernel 2.6.35+ and android 2.3.4+ it will support ADK too, but I can't find a 2.6.35+ kernel for my Milestone.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful information, do you have a source for this? My phone only has a 2.6.29 kernel, so this is probably the reason.

Answer (score 3):

When I was digging around in the CyanogenMod 7.1 kernel sources for my Galaxy S2 I found that the USB accessory driver missing from kernel 2.6.35.7 (I think the kernel .config flag is CONFIG_USB_ANDROID_ACCESSORY).

From what I've found by a lot of searching and forum digging was that the accessory driver was implemented in Honeycomb (3.x) but backported to Gingerbread (2.3), and should be available from kernel 2.6.35.15. I made a few unsuccessful attempts to compile my own kernel, with the plan to cherry pick the driver but for some reason I was not able to make the phone boot with my custom kernel.

I am now running an early experimental CyanogenMod 9 ICS (4.0.3) build on my SGS2 and it is possible to have the phone talk with my Arduino board. I made the phone able to toggle an LED on the board so I guess it is time to start working on my plans for world domination.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, any device running Android 2.3.4+ or 3.1+ should be compatible with the ADK (as long as they have a USB port). I don't think any manufacturers **remove** the ADK from their builds (I don't see why they would), but it's not impossible either.

So, you either update your phone to 2.3.4 (if it's possible), buy a phone that runs 2.3.4+ (the minor version is important -- 2.3.3 does not have the ADK) or buy a tablet that runs 3.1+.

If you're going to buy a phone, I recommend a Google-branded phone, such as the Nexus S.

Comment: I have a phone (LG GT540) running 2.3.4 already (a port of Cyanogenmod), but it does not work, and I have seen many reports of phones not working, but can't find any reports of phones that do work.

Comment: That's pretty weird, since I see the ADK is in the [AOSP](http://android.git.kernel.org/), which is what Cyanogenmod is based on. Are you sure you're running 2.3.4? Cyanogenmod's [about page](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/about) says it's based on 2.3.3.

Comment: The [ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=927379) I am using is actually 2.3.5 (the about screen agrees) although the kernel version is only 2.6.29 (not sure if that is the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Known good: Nexus S (not 4G) running ICS 4.0.4.

ICS 4.0.3 is known *not* to work. Don't know anything about 2.3.x.