# Can't get the Android open accessory kit to work with Samsung galaxy S I9000 / Cyanogenmod 7.1

Tags: android, usb, adk

I have a Galaxy S I9000 with Cyanogenmod 7.1. (Android 2.3.7)
When I try to install Demokit on the device I get :

[2011-10-14 13:01:43 - DemoKit] Installation error:
INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

from logcat:

10-14 13:13:30.675: ERROR/PackageManager(205): Package
com.google.android.DemoKit requires unavailable shared library
com.android.future.usb.accessory; failing!

However, it does work on a Nexus S with the same distribution.
Any ideas?

Thanks,

UPDATE

Managed to install. see link: [http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/14454-cm7-discussion-of-nightlies/page_*st*_260&usg=AFQjCNGMBI-09rbdzYZq7AwY-_BZpsiONw](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/14454-cm7-discussion-of-nightlies/page__st__260&usg=AFQjCNGMBI-09rbdzYZq7AwY-_BZpsiONw)

However, still can't get the DemoKit app to communicate with the arduino board. I get the following in logcat when connecting the USB :

> 10-14 21:15:45.313: ERROR/Setting(1451): Intent Action
>   android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED 10-14 21:15:45.313:
>   ERROR/Setting(1451): Battery charging. plugType =2 10-14 21:15:45.315:
>   ERROR/Setting(1451): Charging is of type USB= 2 10-14 21:15:45.315:
>   ERROR/Settings(1451): [MTP] assume media player mode, USB is
>   connected. 10-14 21:15:45.567: ERROR/OggExtractor(255): readNextPacket
>   err -1004

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote an answer to a similar question that might be of help to you

> When I was digging around in the CyanogenMod 7.1 kernel sources for my Galaxy S2 I found that the USB accessory driver missing from kernel 2.6.35.7 (I think the kernel .config flag for this driver is CONFIG_USB_ANDROID_ACCESSORY).

I have tried several ways to get the ADK to work but the only "solution" to this problem that I've managed to get working was to switch to an experimental release of CyanogenMod 9 (ICS 4.0.3)

Hope this helps

You can read my full answer to the related question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8831987/1144993