# Is Android 4.0 still compatible with the ADK?

Tags: android, adk

I'm thinking about investing in one of the newer android phones, but I am also really involved with developing on the ADK. Does anyone know if Ice Cream Sandwhich works with it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [**official site Android ADK**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html), it should be compatible. And [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256263/which-android-devices-support-the-adk-open-accessory/9341476#9341476) is the List of Supported Android ADK Devices with v2.3.4+ and v3.1+.

Currently, I'm still doing ADK with Samsung galaxy tab 10.1 (with Android 3.2 updated) and still have some problem, check [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338631/android-adk-error-on-galaxy-tab-10-1)

Regards,
pak

Comment: Thanks alot pak! sorry for the late response

Answer (score 0):

In general Ice Cream Sandwich works just fine with the ADK. The Galaxy Nexus has no problems with it whatsoever.

Keep in mind though that it's not only a OS version constraint. The device manufacturer has to integrate a supporting USB chip and the corresponding driver. Sadly there is no official list of supported devices but if you have a device which supports the ADK in an old Android version than it should generally work after an ICS update.

For new devices I would recommend buying a Galaxy Nexus as it is a Google supported Developer phone which has the best API support.

Answer (score 0):

> The Android 3.1 platform (also backported to Android 2.3.4) introduces Android Open Accessory support, which allows external USB hardware (an Android USB accessory) to interact with an Android-powered device in a special "accessory" mode.

I'm guessing this means anything that is currently running ICS stock will support ADK. I have the Galaxy Nexus and HTC incredible 2 (android 2.3) and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I've found is that some phones (e.g. Galaxy S2) don't include the backport for the com.android.future.usb library.

So if you're writing an application to be backwards compatible for gingerbread, it may not work on ICS. You have to rewrite the code using android.hardware.usb, which shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on device because I am not able to run adk mode on micromax tablet which has 4.0.3 and I am able to run adk mode on samsung galaxy S duos which also has 4.0.3 android OS.