# Android ADK error on Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android, tablet, adk

I'm programming android adk program (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/adk.html)  on Samsung galaxy tab 10.1 (version 3.2). I have managed to get it working on simulator by using Google API level 12, but not on actual device.

Here is  [**my DemoKit program**](http://www.mediafire.com/?djcvrukv7oazn0n).

When I run it on galaxy tab, "force to close" error and I have some error on LogCat during downloading and installing DemoKit.apk. I do not know about LogCat so I have attached LogCat file as reference to detect error. 
([**LogCat file for problem DemoKit program**](http://www.mediafire.com/?cr8muggavwa1mio))

Thanks in advance,
pak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Problem(atleast one) is that you are using the wrong USB library. The one you are using can only be used with Android 2.3.4+ for 3.1+ you have to use another one.

You have to change your imports from

```
com.android.future.usb
```

to

```
android.hardware.usb
```

then you need to change your the way you obtain the UsbManager Object from

```
UsbManager manager = UsbManager.getInstance(this);
```

to

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
```

and finally the way you obtain the intent from

```
UsbAccessory accessory = UsbManager.getAccessory(intent);
```

to

```
UsbAccessory accessory = (UsbAccessory) intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
```

edit: more information can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html)