# Bluetooth Accessory and Android Open Accessory Protocol

Tags: android, bluetooth, adk, accessory

I am developing an Android application that should communicate with Bluetooth Accessories (barcode scanners). I am trying to understand what ADK and AOA Protocol 2.0 means for me. I have read ADK 2012 Guide and watched Google I/O 2012 ADK session video.

Please check my questions and verify my answers:

1. Is there anything to be done in Android application for it to adhere to Android Open Accessories protocol 2.0?
   My answer: No, just perform regular Bluetooth connection (as described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)
2. Is there anything to be done in Bluetooth accessory firmware for it to adhere to Android Open Accessories protocol 2.0?
   My answer: No, nothing.
3. Should Android device switch to "accessory mode" when communicating with Bluetooth accessory?
   My answer: No, "accessory mode" is only applicable with USB accessories.
4. Is there a list of supported Android ADK devices for Bluetooth accessories (there is such list for USB accessories: [Which android devices support the ADK / open accessory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256263/which-android-devices-support-the-adk-open-accessory))?
   My answer: No, any device that supports Bluetooth.
5. If I am not using Arduino, is there anything I can take from ADK and AOA?
   My answer: No, not with Bluetooth accessory.

Thanks.